# stripping leading and end commas

Tags: php, regex

hi i've been using the following code for a long time

```
$string = "/,One, Two, Three, Four,,, Five, ,  Six,  , , Seven,./";
$regex = "/^[,\s]+|[\s,]+$/";
echo preg_replace($regex, ',', $string);
```

but it is no longer working since users are having fun inputing commas for no reason all the time

so i tried using this regex `$regex = "/[\s,]+/"`

It did a very fine effect, But not as intended.

What i want to achieve is having no leading or ending special characters at all, Only Alphanumeric characters. And only one comma per separation so my final goal would be something like

from `/,One, Two, Three, Four,,, Five, ,  Six,  , , Seven,./`

to `One, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven`

How to do that exactly?

Comment: What's with the `/` in $string?

Comment: Instead of trying to make sense of nonsensical input, I would simply refuse it if it does not validate. On the other hand you should probably re-think how you ask for this input: Perhaps checkboxes would be a better option than text input.

Comment: Are there cases where having multiple commas in actual values might be valid?

Comment: @MarkBaker just special characters

Comment: Try https://ideone.com/0QjBXU. It trims off specific chars from the start/end, and shrinks `space*(,space*)+` patterns to just `,+space`.

Comment: @RobbieAverill No, Each value is new the moment there is a comma, my last code any leading or ending comma made an empty array, so that made a problem.

Comment: @jeroen i want to clean it, since it is something previewed by the user input, by adding extra commas they create extra values, and make extra empty preview divs

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it gave me `/, One, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, ./` as a final result for my string sample

Comment: So, `/` are part of the string? Sorry, so, what is the rule? Any punctuation at the start/end of string must be removed? See [**this demo**](https://ideone.com/i4j9IS).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The idea is a new word is added to an array with the comma, some people write `word , , another` and the array creates an empty array,same goes with leading commas and ending commas, So i decided to force-clean their strings to be legit, only alphanumeric words separated with commas, not empty, not ending or leading with any special character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using `preg_split` (*with the flag `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY`)* and `implode` is a good way:

```
$parts = preg_split('~[^[:alnum:],]*,[^[:alnum:]]*~', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$result = implode(', ', $parts);
```

Comment: That actually a better method to use, Since i won't need to explode the result, How does the pattern work exactly?

Comment: @Axon: nothing incredible,  it splits on substrings with non alphanumeric characters with at least one comma and excludes empty parts.

Comment: Is it possible to add a replacement for new-line to be replaced with commas if it is not empty?

Answer (score 1):

Use trim() to get rid of the symbols at the beginning and end, then use this regex to convert incorrect usages of commas to correct usages.

You can do that with the following regex:

```
echo preg_replace("/((\W{1,}),(\W{1,}))/", ', ', trim($string, ',./'));
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/0BA2OZ/1/) can walk you through exactly how the regex works.

Answer (score 0):

You can strip off the periods, commas and slashes at the start and end of the string using `trim()`. Then you can use `preg_replace()` to sanitize the mixtures of commas and whitespace in the middle:

```
$string = "/,One, Two, Three, Four,,, Five, , Thirty One, , Six,  , , Seven,./";
$regex = "/\s*,[,\s]+/";
echo preg_replace($regex, ', ', trim($string, ',./'));

// "One, Two, Three, Four, Five, Thirty One, Six, Seven"
```

**Edit** If `trim()` is not enough and you need to cut of all non-alphanumeric characters, you can also use an expression for that. This is not pretty, but it works:

```
$trimmed = preg_replace('/(^[^\w]*)|([^\w]*$)/', '', $string)
```

Comment: This will insert commas where spaces were.

Comment: @rickdenhaan that worked pretty well, But the problem i only want alphanumeric characters, some people may write `&` or `{}` or `[]` and it would pass.

Comment: Only at the beginning and end? Or also in the middle?

Comment: @rickdenhaan you made me notice another problem, I think i'll have to allow specific special characters in the middle, but no special at the end or start. But at this point your code is the solution. But yes, Only alphanumeric at the end and start.

Comment: I've added an option to replace the `trim()` with another `preg_replace()`

Comment: @rickdenhaan the first example would be reasonable since it gives more flexibility.